# How to zoom a circular region with Cocos2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, zooming

I am working on a Cocos2d project for iPad and iPhone, and now I need to develop something that looks too small for iPhone.
My first approach was to redesign it to make it possible to look bigger, but then I though that a region zoom effect would be great. The bad point is that I don't know how to do it... I really don't know what would be the correct/best approach to do it.

I have already checked out the Cocos2D CCLens3D build in effect, but it doesn't give me the results I want.

I would love to get the same result than when you long-press a textview/textfield on the UIKit:
[image: UITextField zoom]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: don't know about the same effect but you can implement a zoom over a sprite using scale. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919180/applying-zoom-effect-in-cocos2d-gaming-environment

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this is not what I want. I want to redisplay a known zone (circular) in another "layer" with a dynamic zoom level. I guess I should work at OpenGL level because I have checked the net and don't found anything yet...

Comment: Don't know i you need to go to the OpenGL level but definitely you need to make it by yourself, maybe a merge with UIKit or something like that. Anyway, if you get this solved it would be nice to read the solution on this post. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, so I have finally redesigned the app to make it better looking with the scale mode... The other approach would have been too complicated.

Comment: Well you solved the problem. Hope that the redesign was not too complicated. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your still looking for a solution:
http://rombosblog.wordpress.com/2012/06/03/magnifierglassforcocos2d/

Uses CoreGraphics to render. Although this implementation works (requires some tweaking), I found that it lacked that Gaussian distribution effect I was looking for and was quite expensive if you updated the magnifying effect in a small interval.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't need this anymore, but I'll keep this info :)